# 'WHERE' syntax equivalent of LEFT OUTER JOIN in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, relational-database

I know there is a `WHERE` representation of `LEFT JOIN` in Oracle that has syntax like:

```
  FROM t1, t2
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+)
```

instead of:

```
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Is there anything similar in PostgreSQL? I searched for documentation, but failed to find such feature.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/003e01c1d65f$b9a01d80$01011eac@irina

Comment: Thanks, pretty useful, but in the following link there is an example of "left join + where clause", not an example of replacing "join" with "where"

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/explicit-joins.html

Comment: Hmm, that's not what I'm really looking for...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such operator in Postgres (or standard SQL).

The only way to write an outer join in Postgres is to use an ANSI explicit JOIN syntax:

```
select *
from table t1
  left join table t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

(or it might be the other way round - it has been *ages* since I last used the Oracle `(+)` operator)

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM

You shouldn't be using the `(+)` operator in Oracle in the first place. Oracle has supported ANSI joins since 9i and Oracle recommends stop using the `(+)` operator (the above statement will work just fine in Oracle as well)

Comment: As i understand, there is no "Oracle (+)" like equivalent in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @DraggonZ No, there isn't. Why do you want that? To not have to rewrite the Oracle query?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto To not to rewrite much existing PostgreSQL query. That query dynamically builds from C# code (something like whereString += tableName + ".id = " + table.Table + "." + tableName + "_id AND ";) It's a legacy code without tests, and I need to replace some wheres with left joins without breaking any other logic.

Comment: @DraggonZ: no there is no such operator in Postgres - and you shouldn't be using it in Oracle either.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you move this to your answer? I'll accept it.